# How to install gpg-zip on Mac OS Mavericks?

Tags: mac, encryption, zip, gnupg

I used to use gpg-zip on my Mac. I recently upgraded my system to Mavericks 10.11.6 and had to reinstall gpg and gpg2. I used homebrew to install gpg2, but gpg-zip wasn't installed. I tried downloading the GUI installer from GnuPG.org, but still no gpg-zip. I've spent a lot of time uninstalling and reinstalling and running various updates and searching Google, but haven't found a solution.

Has anyone gotten gpg-zip to work in Mavericks or later? I'd appreciate any advice. thx

Comment: `gpg-zip` was included in homebrew with the `gnupg2` formula, but dropped off again when the `gnupg` package was updated to 2.1. I'd recommend writing an issue on GitHub, this is only a minor change and the HomeBrew community usually is very fast at dealing with such issues. I'd put together the patch on my own (it's a matter of minutes), but haven't got an OS X development setup at hand right now.